# Stuck in While loop despite condition for loop no longer being met

Tags: ios, swift, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am very new to coding in Swift and right now I am trying to write a program that simply takes a budget and some restaurants and then tries to determine what you'll eat based on the amount of budget that you have remaining. It seems like I have code that should be working but for some reason whenever it goes into the while loop after a certain number of iterations it fails to recognize when totalPrice is no longer greater than budget. If I put an if condition at the end of the while loop verify if totalPrice is greater than budget it will recognize that it isn't and then execute whatever I put in the curly braces but then won't leave the while loop. I am really confused about what is going wrong and would really appreciate some help understanding what's wrong with my code as it is. Thank you so much for the help!

```
import UIKit

var prices = [30,10.99,10.5,11.7,13.99,7.99,8.99,0]
var tips = [0.20,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.15,0.15,0.0]
var restaurants = ["Salty Snow","Kerby Lane","Milto's","Trudy's","Madam Mam's","Vert's","Teji's","Home"]
var daysOfWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
let taxRate = 0.0825
var budget = 50.0

for i in 1...14{
    print("Week \(i)")
    for day in daysOfWeek {
        var randInt = Int.random(in:0..<8)
        var totalPrice = prices[randInt]+(prices[randInt]*taxRate)+(prices[randInt]*tips[randInt])
        while totalPrice > budget {
            var randInt = Int.random(in:0..<8)
            var totalPrice = prices[randInt]+(prices[randInt]*taxRate)+(prices[randInt]*tips[randInt])
        }
        print(totalPrice, randInt, budget)
        var place = restaurants[randInt]
        budget = budget - totalPrice
        print("\(day) meal: \(place), budget now \(budget)")

    }
    print()
    budget += 50
}
```

Comment: what you want to achieve bro ? from that many loops

Comment: You create a new `totalPrice` variable inside the while loop so it is not same as you use in the condition of the `while` loop. Change `var totalPrice = ...` to `totalPrice = ...` inside the `while` loop. For cases like this it would be a good thing to use the debugger. Voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: yup I am an idiot thank you so much

Comment: Well we all do simple mistakes from time to time and like I said the debugger is a great tool to find those mistakes. BTW, you are doing the same thing with `randInt`, is it intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `var` from totalPrice variable in while loop... because its not changing but creating new variable each time

```
 while totalPrice > budget {
    var randInt = Int.random(in:0..<8)
        totalPrice = prices[randInt]+(prices[randInt]*taxRate)+(prices[randInt]*tips[randInt])
  //var totalPrice = prices[randInt]+(prices[randInt]*taxRate)+(prices[randInt]*tips[randInt])
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you added the `var totalPrice` instead of updating the `totalPrice` in the while loop, you defined a new variable with the same name and that is why the conditions never matched and it became an infinite loop. Use this:

```
var prices = [30,10.99,10.5,11.7,13.99,7.99,8.99,0]
var tips = [0.20,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.18,0.15,0.15,0.0]
var restaurants = ["Salty Snow","Kerby Lane","Milto's","Trudy's","Madam Mam's","Vert's","Teji's","Home"]
var daysOfWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
let taxRate = 0.0825
var budget = 50.0

for i in 1...14{
print("Week \(i)")
for day in daysOfWeek {
    let randInt = Int.random(in:0..<8)
    var totalPrice = prices[randInt]+(prices[randInt]*taxRate)+(prices[randInt]*tips[randInt])
    while totalPrice > budget {
        let randInt = Int.random(in:0..<8)
        totalPrice = prices[randInt]+(prices[randInt]*taxRate)+(prices[randInt]*tips[randInt])
        print(totalPrice, randInt, budget)

    }
    let place = restaurants[randInt]
    budget = budget - totalPrice
    print("\(day) meal: \(place), budget now \(budget)")

}
print()
budget += 50
}
```